# detecting object causing memory leak in C#

Tags: c#, memory-leaks, crash-dumps

How to detect objects causing memory leaks in .net. Is it possible to detect object causing memory leaks using crash-dumps?

Comment: related: [How do I take a good crash dump for .NET](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24874027/how-do-i-take-a-good-crash-dump-for-net)

Comment: also needed: [How to set up symbols in WinDbg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30019889/how-to-set-up-symbols-in-windbg)

Answer (score 0):

To detect and investigate memory leaks in .NET you have several options:

1. Use a memory profiler tool like [RedGate's ANTS](http://www.red-gate.com/products/dotnet-development/ants-memory-profiler/) (many other similar tools are available).
2. Use WinDBG with its [SOS](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx) extension.
3. Instrument your app yourself with a memory leak detector based on weak references.

To use crash dumps in the investigation of memory leaks see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9514401/how-do-i-use-a-dump-file-to-diagnose-a-memory-leak) stackoverflow question and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/06/20/using-visual-studio-2013-to-diagnose-net-memory-issues-in-production.aspx) MSDN link.

Answer (score 0):

Having one dump (and if it has been taken properly see this [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/tess/archive/2006/01/11/back-to-basics-how-do-i-get-the-memory-dumps-in-the-first-place-and-what-is-sos-dll.aspx)) maybe, having multiple dumps most certainly.

What you can do:

- If you haven´t already, install the Windows SDK to get the Debugging Tools for Windows
- If you have an x86 process (note: the architecture of the process is relevant, not the architecture of the system running the process) use WinDBG (x86), otherwise use the x64 Version.
- Go File - Open Crash Dump, locate your dump file and open it
- assuming your process is .net 4, in the debugger enter

  `.loadby sos clr` followed by `!dumpheap -stat`
- This will output the count and class name of managed types.
- Having multiple dumps will make it easier for your, but certainly not as easy as being able to use a Memory profiler