# Visual Studio 2017 keeps locking up and making memory dumps

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2017, dump

Every day or two Visual Studio 2017 locks up completely (eg UI won't respond) however it maintains the message pump as it doesn't show as not responding.

Looking in resource monitor I see it is making a "Low Memory Dump" which takes about 45 seconds. After this dump VS continues on as if nothing has happened with no errors anywhere to be seen.

[image]

When I check the temp folder the dump file is missing.

How do I determine what is causing the memory dump to occur? Where is this logged?

Comment: Why is this downvoted? If you downvote it please comment otherwise you just annoy everyone.

Comment: Upvoted to negate the downvote, but sorry I can't help you. Does this happen specifically while compiling or debugging, or does it just seem to happen at random?

Comment: Random. I use vs all day every day.

Comment: LowMemory indicates you run out of virtual memory (4GB as VS2017 is large address aware x86 program). Perfwatson seams to detect this and try to create telemetry dumps to see which dll causes most allocations.

Comment: @magicandre1981 the same happens to me on VS2020, is there a way to disable it?

Comment: @SlimShaggy I have no idea, try VS2022 as it is 64bit and no longer has the 4GB limit

Comment: @magicandre1981 oops, that's a typo, VS2022 64-bit is what I use. It froze and started to write the low memory dump when it had some 6 GB allocated.

Comment: @SlimShaggy analyze the [dumps with Windbg](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9519738/1466046)

Comment: @magicandre1981 I found a suggestion to turn off Visual Studio Experience Improvement Program in Help -> Privacy Settings, no dumps so far.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with VS2022. Turning off Visual Studio Experience Improvement Program in Help -> Privacy -> Privacy Settings seems to prevent writing those dumps.